# Uniqueness/Existence ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

here's my question

Consider the differential equation: 
$t\frac{dg}{dt} = 2g.$

I got that the general solution is $g = ct^2$. However, I don't understand how to answer these questions:

- What is the unique solution for the IVP $g(-1) = -1$ on the interval $-2 < t < 0$. What is the largest interval on which the solution is unique?

I think the answer is $g=-t^2$.   Then, that would mean that the maximum interval is $-\infty < t <0$.  Right?

- Using the same IVP, what are three possible solutions for $-2 < t <2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your answer is right. For the very last part, your original solution (call it $f$) certainly works in $-2 < t < 2$. Since the solution has to satisfy the initial condition, so it must be $f$ on $-2 < x \leq 0$. At $0$, it can switch to a different function, i.e. any solution which in general has the form $ct^2$. So the following is the general solution and you can get three specific one by choosing three specific constants $c$.
$$
h(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & -2 < x \leq 0 \\
ct^2 & 0 \leq x < 2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I am not in total agreement.  It seems to me that the solutions should be $$h(x) = \cases{f(x)&if $-2<x\le0$\cr ct^2&if $0\le x<2$}$$ where $c$ can be any real number.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I agree your solution is more general, but my definition of $h$ still works (special case of your solution with $c = 0$). The last question only asks for three _possible_ solutions anyway.

Comment: Yes, but $g$ isn't a solution.  It doesn't satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Oh right, that's true. I'll fix that. But $h$ still satisfies the initial conditions.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thanks for the correction. I think I have it correct now.